# Writing a batch script to copy files based on date

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, script

I have a folder on a local PC that updates files through Dropbox. I have created a batch script that runs through a scheduler each day.

So far it checks to see if a folder is empty (`C:\TheGlenFTP\sendho`) before running some xcopy commands. I would like to add a condition to this script - that it also only runs the xcopy commands if the file
`C:\Users\user\Dropbox\Combined\orderhea.dat` is timestamped with today’s date.

Can any of you help with this?

This is the batch script so far.

```
@Echo off
Setlocal
Set _folder="C:\TheGlenFTP\sendho"
For /F %%A in ('dir /b /a %_folder%') Do (
    Echo The folder is NOT empty
    goto :ok
)
xcopy C:\TheGlenFTP\combined\*.* c:\Holdsworth\Data\ /y /c
xcopy C:\Holdsworth\Programs\xmit.ok C:\Holdsworth\Data\
:ok
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "_dt_file=//null..."
set "_file=C:\Users\user\Dropbox\Combined\orderhea.datafile"

>nul 2>&1 dir /a:a /b "C:\TheGlenFTP\sendho\." && =;(
    
     echo\The folder is NOT empty^!!... & exit /b 

    );= || =;(

     for /f usebackq^tokens^=4delims^=^<^>. %%G in =;(`
         2^>nul wmic datafile where name^="%_file:\=\\%" get lastmodified /format:xml ^| find "VALUE&"
           `);= do call set "_dt_file=%%~G"
             
     for /f usebackq^tokens^=4delims^=^<^>. %%i in =;(`
        2^>nul wmic os get LocalDateTime /format:xml ^| find "VALUE&" 
           `);= do call set "_today=%%~i"
     
     if "!_today:~0,8!" == "!_dt_file:~0,8!" =;(
         
         xcopy "C:\TheGlenFTP\combined\*.*" "c:\Holdsworth\Data\" /y /c
         xcopy "C:\Holdsworth\Programs\xmit.ok" 'C:\Holdsworth\Data\"
        
        );= else echo/Today !_today:~0,8! differs file date !_dt_file:~0,8!
        
    );= 

endlocal
```

---